# problema con asincronismo en Node Js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, asincronismo

Tengo un problema en Nodejs, la variable sessionData obtiene su valor de una base de datos, en el caso de que ese valor exista se debe de ejecutar new client, el problema que tengo es que cuando ejecuto todo el código primero en ejecutarse es new client y luego se obtienen los datos de sessionData, como puedo hacer para que primero se obtenga el valor de sessionData y luego se ejecute new client

```
let sessionData

(async() => {  
    sessionData = await cargarSession()
    console.log('Mi objeto recibido', sessionData)

    //return sessionData
})();

const wa = new Client({
    restartOnAuthFail: true,
    puppeteer: {
        headless: true,
        args: [
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
            '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
            '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
            '--no-first-run',
            '--no-zygote',
            '--single-process', 
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--use-gl=egl'
        ],
    }, 
    session: sessionData
})
```

Comment: Hola, podrías probar a insertar la constante "wa" (con todo el código) en la primera función, después del console.log() . Notifícame si te funciona. Saludos

Comment: si ya lo intente, lo que sucede es que mas abajo tengo una funcion que necesita de wa pero si a esta la inserto dentro de la primera funcion el scope no me permite que esa funcion pueda acceder a los valores de wa

Answer (score 1):

El problema es la función asíncrona, si quieres que algún código síncrono se ejecute luego de una código asíncrono debe estar en el mismo scope, algo que puede llegar a funcionar es lo siguiente

```
async function cargarWa() {
  const sessionData = await cargarSession();
  console.log('Mi objeto recibido', sessionData);

  const wa = new Client({
    restartOnAuthFail: true,
    puppeteer: {
      headless: true,
      args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
        '--no-first-run',
        '--no-zygote',
        '--single-process',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--use-gl=egl',
      ],
    },
    session: sessionData,
  });

  return {
    wa, 
    sessionData
  }
}

const { wa, sessionData } = cargarWa()

wa.example()
console.log(sessionData)
```

Otra forma puede ser modificando la clase `Client`, y que utilice el método `cargarSession` en el constructor y luego acceder a `sessionData` a través de `Client`